# C , How to find 2 repeating words in a string and count the distance between them

Tags: c, distance, strtok, words, repeat

From what i understand i need to use the the strtok function but i have no idea what to do next. Please help.

This is literally how far i've gotten :

```
printf("Write a sentence\n");
gets(text);
token=strtok(text, " ");
```

I understand that i have to split the string into segments (words), but i have no idea what do i do after that.

Comment: Ten hours is plenty of time. What was your specific problem?

Comment: For more information about the kinds of questions and the quality of them, there is a [faq] as well as a [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section.  Those really help when you're new to the site to learn the correct way to ask questions.  There is also a [nice checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) on meta that could help out as well.

Comment: my problem is that i don't know how do i find 2 repeated words.

Comment: @user3014914 To test if two words are the same, you could try using a function like `strcmp()`. If you need to check multiple pairs of words, perhaps some sort of loop structure would help?

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage could you please give me an example in code?

Comment: @user3014914 You've got nine hours and 45 minutes left. Try figuring it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `strtok` to split the input string into words.
Then, I will add each word to a *hashtable*: the keys would be the words, and the values would be the word's first occurrence position.
When inserting a new word into the *hashtable*, if the world is already there, then I'd compute the distance between the current position and that word's position.

Hope it helps.